# Tkinter destroying an object in a different function isn't working

Tags: python, function, tkinter, destroy

I'm trying to make a button that saves your username but then goes away after you set it.
this is my code:

```
def printValue():
        User = Name.player_name.get()
        label.config(text=f'Hi, {User}')
        Name.button.destroy()
        Name.player_name.destroy()
def Name():
        label.config(text="What's your name?")
        Name.player_name = Entry(root)
        Name.player_name.pack(pady=15)
        Name.button = Button(text="Change", command=printValue)
        Name.button.pack()
```

Comment: In what exact way is it not working?  If there was an error, we need to see the full traceback message.

Comment: no error, it just doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below, with some minor changes like enabling change with `[Return]` and some layout cosmetics works OK (also with un-commented lines in `printValue`) . If you want the `[Change]` button and the entry area to go away un-comment the two lines turned into comments in the `printValue` function:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671126/tkinter-destroying-an-object-in-a-different-function-isnt-working
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop, Entry, Button, Label

root = Tk()
label = Label(root, font=('',12), padx=15, pady=5)
label.pack()

def Name():
    label.config(text="What's your name?")
    Name.player_name = Entry(root, font=('',12))
    Name.player_name.pack(padx=15, pady=15)
    Name.player_name.focus()
    Name.button      = Button(text="Change", command=printValue)
    Name.button.pack()

def printValue(event=None):
    User = Name.player_name.get()
    # Name.player_name.destroy()
    # Name.button.destroy()
    label.config(text=f'Hi, {User}')

Name()

root.bind("<Return>", printValue)

mainloop()
```

By the way: **The in the question provided code demonstrates an interesting approach of making names of variables global by setting function attributes in the function itself.** This way it is possible to assign values in one function and retrieve them in another without passing return values or declaring variables global. I am not aware of already having seen such approach used in Python code here on stackoverflow. How does it come you use such code?

Comment: It isn't news to me, but be aware that this behavior only apply to free functions not class methods.

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it properly, is why. I'm not good at using global variables and instead do it like that.

Comment: @Thingamabobs : `class C: def f(self): C.f.attr = ' >> C.f.attr'` and then `C.f(None); print(C.f.attr)` gives ' >> C.f.attr'. In **class** functions the function name must be proceeded by the class name to set the attribute value. Then in a 'free' global function `def f(): print('def f():', C.f.attr)` the `C.f.attr` value is known and will be printed. I must admit I don't really understand how it comes ...

Comment: @Chickenman : though you accepted my answer I still don't understand what your problem/question actually was as your code did what it should as it was and the destroying of widgets in the different function worked OK. Hmmm ... **WHAT** was your problem and what didn't work?

Comment: @Claudio see this [PEP 232](https://peps.python.org/pep-0232/) for function attributes.

Comment: @Claudio Sorry for the late reply, but basically I was trying to make a personal assistant that does actions when you right click it. this one was going to set your username so it can call you by that. it's supposed to create a text box, then delete it when you hit change. however, that didn't work. I don't know why it didn't work, it didn't give me an error or anything, it just didn't work.